# C Segmentation Fault when trying strcpy on char *pointer

Tags: c, memory, string, pointers

I'm new in learning the C-Language and I have a question to pointers.

For Example if I try this:

```
char *pointer;
strcpy(pointer,"Hello, World!\n");
printf(pointer);
```

I get this Output:

```
Segmentation Fault
```

But if I try this:

```
char *pointer = "Hello, World!\n");
printf(pointer);
```

I get this:

```
Hello, World!
```

My question is why it isn't working with `strcpy`.
The functions do the same overall.

What is the difference between the first sourcecode and the second?

It would be good if someone could explain what is happening in the memory, so that I can get a better view at this.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char* pointer` merely gives you a variable to use to access the memory location. You've not yet allocated any memory, so when you do the `strcpy` you're writing to whatever random/undefined value `pointer` has.

You need to do something like:

```
char* pointer = calloc(LEN);
if (pointer)
{
    strcpy(pointer, "Hello World");
    printf(pointer);
    free(pointer);
}
```

Comment: Using `strncpy()` would be safer.

Comment: Ah, ok. So let's say I have

    `char *pointer`

then the adress of pointer in my memory is for example 0xBFFFF800

but at this adress is a random value, then pointer points to the random location saved at 0xBFFFF800 right?

Comment: @user3605865 yes, and the next byte might be anything. It might be the shutdown hook for your operating system, it might be the control code to start global thermonuclear war (if it's a computer running that kind of software)... That's why you should always allocate memory, to prevent attempts to write into (or read out of) memory you're not supposed to access.

Comment: `calloc` takes 2 parameters, so use `calloc(LEN, 1)`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you guys! You where a big help :*

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to "strcpy" should be pointing to a usable location in memory. In your first source code, you havent initialized "pointer" to anything. You should first initialize it, for example by declaring it to be an array of characters of maximum length:

```
char myArray[42]; // where 42 represents the maximum capacity
```

Comment: Good point--corrected